# Не выдавать 503 ошибку при limit_conn perip?

Tags: nginx

Для поддомена, который раздает (через прямые ссылки) большие файлы doc, zip используется `limit_conn perip 1;`. На странице часто бывает несколько ссылок на скачивание файлов, и пользователь, кликнув по одной, если кликнет сразу другую (если заказчка еще не завершилась) получит 503 ошибку nginx. Подскажите, какой параметр добавить в конфиг nginx, чтобы вместо 503 ошибки, просто продолжалось бы ожидание (окончание скачивания) и после окончания первого скачивания, начиналось сразу следующее.

Comment: Я вам qna предложил использовать limit_req вместо limit_conn.

Answer (score 0):

На уровне Nginx это решить нельзя. Решайте эту проблему на уровне фронта js-ом: закончилась скачка - появилась следующая ссылка.